# MS SQL 2008 Express - Database Tuning Advisor

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-tuning-advisor

I want to use DTA, but on my website I have an Express Server version.
Can I backup my DB on Express server, restore it on my personal computer with Enterprise Version, make some tuning by DTA and then restore it back on webserver Express MS SQL? Are they compatible? Both MS SQL 2008 R2, but one is Express and second not.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't enable any features that aren't supported on Express Edition, you should be fine. For example I think you can use DTA to recommend table partitioning which obviously won't work on Express edition. The other thing to think about is that the server running Enterprise Edition might have a lot more memory or CPUs, so the optimizer on that server might make much different plan choices than it will on your web server.

Comment: I just want to make indexes. Is that somehow connected to CPU?

Comment: Absolutely, if your dev machine has 4 CPUs it may consider one plan shape that is not optimal on your production machine that has 1 or 2 CPUs (or 16), and derive index suggestions off that choice. You probably won't see too much difference but it is something to be aware of.

Comment: On my website I have poor conditions, even maybe my home machine is stronger. My question is there some differences between backup versions that I couldn't restore it back on Express. Some stucture changes maybe...

Comment: If the version on your web site is newer (2008 R2, for example), then no you won't be able to restore it to your local copy of, say, 2005 or 2008. The version of the instance you're restoring *to* has  to be >= the version of the instance from which the backup came.

Comment: Both 2008 versions

Comment: Well can you define "couldn't restore it"? Do you get an error message? What is it? What are the exact `SELECT @@VERSION;` results on each server? Does the production database use features that aren't supported in Express? Please include details when you say something is broken.

Comment: I mean "maybe". I didn't try yet.